# Use a scope with class_name in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I am using rails 5.1 with mongoid.

I have a class with a scope

```
class Attachment
    scope :documents, -> { where(is_document: true) }
```

Then on another class that Attachment refers to I want to get all the attachments that are documents.

```
class User
  has_many :documents, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: :user_id
```

The above selects all the attachments and does not take account scope documents that collect all is_document equals with true.

Comment: Presumably, the not-working call is something like `@user.documents`, which is calling the method `documents` that is defined by your `has_many` declaration on `User`. This returns an ActiveRecord enumerable that has available the method `documents` that is defined by your `scope` declaration on `Attachment`. So, have you tried `@user.documents.documents`?

Answer (score -1):

You can pass scope as proc, in your `has_many` association

```
class User
  has_many :documents, -> { documents }, class_name: 'Attachment', foreign_key: :user_id
end
```